# NodeJS MSSQL results to JSON array

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to create an array of JSON objects from an SQL Server query using NodeJS but using just `JSON.Stringify` on each row I get the results I am looking for as all individual JSON objects but not in an array.  Ideally I am just trying to write these results to a file as a JSON array.  Any ideas appreciated.

Tried the following

```
const sql=require('mssql');
const fs=require('fs');


const config = {
// Creds removed
    },
};


sql.connect(config, err => {
  console.log(err);

  const request = new sql.Request()
  request.stream = true // You can set streaming differently for each request
  request.query(fs.readFileSync('./new-query.sql').toString()); // or request.execute(procedure)

  request.on('row', row => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    
})

  request.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
    // May be emitted multiple times
})
  
  request.on('done', result => {
    // console.log('done emitted', result);  
    sql.close();
  })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `row`s to an array and then `JSON.stringify()` the array just once in the `done` handler?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning I thin you are correct, with the MSSQL library I figured out you can just stringify the entire returned recordset/object as opposed to on the returned Columns.

Answer (score 0):

As always, reading the library notes in more detail led me to a solution.  Using the MSSQL library you can actually work on the entire returned recordset as opposed to every column.  Using this code works as I was wanting it to.

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const fs=require('fs');


const config = {
// cred removed
};


sql.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sql.query(fs.readFileSync('./new-query.sql').toString())
}).then(result => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.recordsets[0]))
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
})
```